Is there a way to create multi-file output using the "same" stream?
I would like to do the following, but am finding it impossible:
    private StreamWriter? _msw;
    private _outputCount = 0;

    if (_idRun % LargeNumber == 0)
    {
        _msw?.Close();
        _msw ??= new StreamWriter("BlahBlah" + _outputCount.ToString() + ".txt");
        _outputCount++;
    }


The idea is simple. If the file being written gets large, close it and open another file of a similar name with a different index. The failure here is the Stream being closed holds its initial filename and does not allow it to "morph" into the new file. The specific error is
Unhandled exception. System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot write to a closed TextWriter.
How might I accomplish this?
I could imagine creating, say, 20 separate filestreams for output, but that seems wasteful. Also, I have the feeling that the output is going to generate many GB of data, and 20 (or 30 or 300) would be limiting.

That code looks fine.  Can you include a short, complete repro in your question?

Is this for writing bytes or text? For the latter, you might probably want to use a StringWriter/TextWriter instead. You could make your own implementation to change the underlying stream after a certain threshold. Or if this is for logging, libraries already implement this behavior.

Are you using the StreamWriter in a multi threaded environment and you have not synchronized the shown code in any way?

If you call SteamWriter.Close the method will call Dispose(true), so you are closing and disposing it, but the reference is still available. That's why you don't create a new one with ??=, causing the ObjectDisposedException if you try to use it.
So this should work as expected(if there is no other issue in your code):
if (_idRun % LargeNumber == 0)
{
    _msw?.Close();
    _msw = new StreamWriter("BlahBlah" + _outputCount.ToString() + ".txt");
    _outputCount++;
}


That solved the problem. The original code had the ??= in it because, originally, it did not seem as if the recursive function would yield many results. Obviously, I was wrong. My work with nullable entities needs to improve. Thank you for the help.
